# A suggested edit was submitted without any changes

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/210

The rendered output view shows no changes, and the markdown view only shows *x identical lines skipped*

I rejected it as spam, based on the comment being a Facebook link, but I don't understand how this got submitted.

> [image: rendered output view]
>
> [image: markdown view]

Another case, [from the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231328/a-suggested-edit-was-submitted-without-any-changes#comment769514_231328): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/598

Comment: This is only happening on Meta SO (an probably on other Meta sites). No issue on MSE and SO Main.

Comment: This seems a fairly poor way of introducing spam content. Are the edit comments indexed? I can't imagine anyone who actually takes the time to read them being fooled into visiting one of the spam links.

Comment: @JonathanGarber not indexed. There are two ways to see those comments, as far as I can tell, one is the [direct suggested edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/210) and the other is via the [wiki revisions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250267/revisions). Both are disallowed in [robots.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt). (`Disallow: /posts/` and `Disallow: /review/*`)

Comment: Someone dared to edit spam into the mighty Shog9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be fixed. Just tested it out on Meta Stack Overflow, as the screenshot in the question points to MSO. Empty edits do not go through review cycle and are also not visible in history.

Comment: Sure you tried to submit empty edit for a tag wiki? It's different from the ordinary edits for posts

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, edited tag wiki without making any changes. I reproduced it last year but not unable to do that today.